# Angular Firebase when deployed but the page is blank

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I deployed Angular project on firebase without problem but when i enter the website, nothing but a blank page appears.How can i solve this problem i am not getting any error.

1.ng build --configuration "production"

2.firebase init

3.Are you ready to proceed? (Y/n) Y

4.>(*) Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys

5.What do you want to use as your public directory? (public) dist/estelaa

6.Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? (y/N) y

7.Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? (y/N) n

8.File dist/estelaa/index.html already exists. Overwrite? (y/N) n

9.firebase deploy

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.css" />
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.1.0/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.iyzipay.com/plugins/v1/iyzico-buttons.min.js"></script>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&family=Orbitron&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Calienna Studio | Official Website</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.jpg">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root class="asd"></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

firebase.json :

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/estelaa",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you add your question to the end of the hosting log file? From what you said, I haven't found any issues that could cause this.

Comment: If possible, the requests your browser is making when accessing the link would also be useful for debugging.

Comment: @GabrielNexT ım sory where is hosting log file

Comment: can you share your `manifest.json`? because, given that you are setting it up as a SPA, the build expects a `baseUrl` in the manifest.json and the prod build should also include this

Comment: do a simple test: if your firebase url would be estelaa.web.app, update your prod build step with `--baseHref=https://estelaa.web.app/` and check if that resolves the blank page issue

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli Error: Unknown argument: baseHref  and There is no  manifest.json

Comment: my bad, try `--base-href` as seen in https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: @pennylies, I hope you are doing all the commands that you have mentioned in your question from the root directory of your project